# getting error LNK2019 when i use std::auto_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, lnk2019

i ahve a class named FiniteStateMachine declared as below

header file : FiniteStateMachine.h

```
class FiniteStateMachine
{
    public:
        //Constructor
        FiniteStateMachine();

        //Destructor
        ~FiniteStateMachine();
}
```

source file : FiniteStateMachine.cpp

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Constructor
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
FiniteStateMachine::FiniteStateMachine()
:m_InitialState("")
,m_CurrentState(NULL)
,m_Running(false)
{
    RegisterBaseTypes();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Destructor
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
FiniteStateMachine::~FiniteStateMachine()
{
    if (m_Running) Stop();
    Clear();
}
```

and ihave a heade file named FSM that i collect all class of project in it

FSM.H

```
class ICORE_API FiniteStateMachine;
```

ok i compile it and now wanna to use this class in another library.

**every thing about linking that library has been done.**

in the client class when i use FiniteStateMachine with auto_ptr i get linker error :

```
#include "FSM.H"

std::auto_ptr<FiniteStateMachine > fsm;

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall IFSM::FiniteStateMachine::~FiniteStateMachine(void)" (??1FiniteStateMachine@IFSM@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall FSM::FiniteStateMachine::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GFiniteStateMachine@IFSM@@QAEPAXI@Z)
```

but by declaring such as this

```
#include FSM.h

FiniteStateMachine* fsm;
```

every thing is ok and project completely compiled.

now i want to know why this happen? what is wrong here.

Comment: Class name is `FiniteStateMachine`, ctor/dtor name mismatches with `IFiniteStateMachine`. This shouldn't compile. Also use `unique_ptr` if you can, not `auto_ptr`.

Comment: sorry it is typing error

Comment: "every thing about linking that library has been done" => obviously not, since you get a *linker* error. Do you include `FiniteStateMachine.obj` in the build?

Comment: Try adding a `delete fsm;` at the end of the one that is working.  Does it still compile after that?

Comment: everything about linking library has been done because in that library i have several classes that i use them.

Comment: when i add delete fsm for working one again i got linker 2019 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::auto_ptr<>` generates the code to call the `FiniteStateMachine`'s destructor and in your case you don't provide it, because you only provide by giving the forward declaration.